# Can't Drag drop files to datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

So I made an application, and now I wanted to implement drag and drop feature. 
Now while it works ANYWHERE in the Form, when I try to drag it on datagridview, I get the 'cancel' icon.

I have set datagridview allowdrop property to true, subscribed the drag events. Datagrid is visble and enabled.

Could it be a matter of its container (splitcontainer-> tabcontrol -> tabpage, but so far I made no difference by setting all of its containers property allowdrop=true)? What am I missing?

@EDIT the code for the events. Won't help much though.

```
void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
        if (files.Count() == 1)
        {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(files[0]) && files[0].Substring(files[0].LastIndexOf('.') + 1).ToLower().Contains("xls"))
            {
                loadExcel(files[0]);

            }
        }
    }
void Form1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop)) e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }

void DGW_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text)) e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }
void DGW_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
            string head = (string)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
            //the same follow up code  as in the form1_dragdrop 
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your code for the `DragDrop` event, and `DragEnter` event if you have one?

Comment: I edited the question  with code included, but I'm afraid It won't help much.

Comment: Can you confirm your DataGridView is named `DGW`?

Comment: Yeah it is. And I have them subscribed in the Form_onload event.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything out of the ordinary in the code provided. You can try removing the events on your `Form1` and seeing what that does. Also, you can set a breakpoint on the `DGW_DragEnter` event and see if it is firing. If you're willing to go to more extremes, try creating a new project, quickly dump a DGV in the form, give it an event and see if it fires, then compare your code. Unfortunately I'm not seeing enough information to properly point you in the right direction.

Comment: The events aren't firing. I made new project to test this and it seems panels need to have events subscribed.
This doesn't apply to all fo the containers though, where all you need to do is set AloowDrag to false and they 'inherit' the feature from the Form itself. Weird.

Comment: I believe the error is in the test for `GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text`. You are doing drarg&drop, so anything you drag from the system will come in as a file and therefore you should test it for `FileDrop`. The Text format is probably only for situations where some programm has actually set that format to be available. Copying text will do that.. The rest runs fine and no, you don't have to allow dragging in the intermediate conatainers, unless you want it work there.

Comment: @TaW problem was with the events not firing. I still dont know why, but apparently you can't subscribe two dragdrop & dragenter events in the same form, or at least I didn't figure out how to do that. 

Basicly I left only Form1 dragenter & dragdrop events while the rest I made sure was set to allowdrop to false, and it suddenly worked.

Comment: Each control can subsribe to a dragenter etc event of its own, if you want to treat them differently.  There is nothing spacial to do, other than setting AllowDrop to true and subscribing.You could even subrscribe one control/form to two different events (but would have to code them in a reasonable way..)